Baseline Profile Generation Question i dont really see explained
i followed the Guidelines to generate Baseline Profile Generation. And it works good so far for me.
The only thing i dont understood is why it looks like the Baseline Generation gets triggered multiple times.
If i create a User Journey i walk initial tru some onboarding but thats just the first time. On next iteration the tests waits in first screen and runs in the timeout.
   @Test
    fun generate() {
        // The application id for the running build variant is read from the instrumentation arguments.
        rule.collect(
            packageName = InstrumentationRegistry.getArguments().getString("targetAppId")
                ?: throw Exception("targetAppId not passed as instrumentation runner arg"),

            // See: https://d.android.com/topic/performance/baselineprofiles/dex-layout-optimizations
            includeInStartupProfile = true
        ) {
            // This block defines the app's critical user journey. Here we are interested in
            // optimizing for app startup. But you can also navigate and scroll through your most important UI.

            // Start default activity for your app
            pressHome()
            startActivityAndWait()
            goThruOnboarding()

Is it just me who find all examples by google way to trivial or do i miss something here ?
Thanks!

The test is run multiple times to compare the output and achieve the best outcome.
The collect method is documented as follows:

Collects baseline profiles for a critical user journey, while ensuring that the generated profiles are stable for a minimum of stableIterations.

Modifying the Number of Runs (not recommended to fix your problem)
You can customize the number of runs for the collect method using the following parameters:

maxIterations


Maximum number of iterations to run when collecting profiles.


stableIterations


Minimum number of iterations to observe as stable before assuming stability, and completing profile generation.

Writing Consistent Tests
Ensure that every iteration of your test performs the same actions. For example, if your onboarding process sets a key in memory so it doesn’t show again, reset the memory before each iteration by using:
device.executeShellCommand("pm clear $packageName")

This method ensures consistency and reliability of the test outcomes.
